# Why is my React / TypeScript app generating a compile error?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've downloaded the following app (which works in the sandbox):

https://codesandbox.io/s/wbkd-react-flow-forked-78hxw4

Locally, after I run:

`npm install`

and then

`npm start`

I get the following error:

```
TypeScript error in /wbkd-react-flow-forked/src/components/ErrorBoundary.tsx(6,15):
Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type.  TS7006

    4 | 
    5 | export class ErrorBoundary extends Component {
  > 6 |   constructor(props) {
      |               ^
    7 |     super(props);
    8 |     this.state = { hasError: false };
    9 |   }
```

How do I resolve the compile error?

Comment: Please include the relavent code in the question, do not link to external resources

Comment: You don't seem to use _strong-typed_ props, hence the error. https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/class_components/

Comment: you don't use typescript in the project but  file extension is tsx. Change it to ErrorBoundary.jsx

Answer (score 1):

Add typing to your props:

```
type ErrorBoundaryProps = {
  someProps: boolean;
}

export class ErrorBoundary extends Component<ErrorBoundaryProps> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { hasError: false };
  }
}
```